# How to load database data to table using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, display

I want to display my database record in a table, but I don't get it. I don't know whats wrong in my code but it displays empty result. I have attached my model and view. I am using codeigniter framework. Any help would be much appreciated..

Here is my model:

```
public function display_data(){     
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sales_rep_tbl;");              
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
            $this->table->set_heading(
            "SR_Code",
            "SR_Fname"
            );
    foreach($query->result() as $r){

        $bg = "black";
            $this->table->add_row(
                    "<div class = '".$bg."'>".$r->SR_Code."</div>",
                    "<div class = '".$bg."'>".$r->SR_Lname."</div>",
                    "<div class = '".$bg."'>".$r->SR_Fname."</div>"         
            );
        $data.= $this->table->generate().br();
        }   
    return $data;
    }  
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class = "container" >
<div class = "row" style = " height:400px; width:auto; margintop:20px;" >
            <div class = "col-xs-12">

                        <?php echo $this->Main_Page_Model->display_data();?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are You displaying data direct from the model? If you are using a Framework then you should follow the rules.

Comment: its only a week since im using codeigniter framework, and it really confusing aout mvc. thats why i didnt know what really is correct. can you teach me ?

Comment: Please see my answer.  For Codeigniter, I will say you must see the user guide first. It's all there.  It's too easy to understand. Follow this link. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow the MVC structure of CI.

You Controller Should be:

```
 public function veiw_table() {
    $data= $this->yourModel->yourfunction();
    $this->load->view('yourViewPage', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Your Model Should Be:

```
 public function yourfunction() {

    $query = $this->db-
     ->select('*')        
    ->get('yourTableName');

    return $query ->result();

 }
```

IN View:

```
foreach ($data as $singleData){
echo $singleData->columnNam;

}
```

Hope This will Help You